# Removing the space after a div in HTML

Tags: html, css

This question seems pretty simple, but I'm having some troubles with it.

If I have two divs, given these styles:

```
<div class="col col20">
    Content left
</div>
<div class="col col80">
    Content right
</div>
```

It will create two divs (and in my stylesheet, one has `width:20%` and the other `width:80%`.  However, there's still a space after the div, because the newline between each tag counts as a space.  Without making my HTML hideous by doing `</div><div...`, what can I do to get rid of this space?

I've tried Googling various things like 'html space after div' and such, but I just get a bunch of newbie questions asking about CSS margins and whatnot.  Sorry!

EDIT: Currently the CSS is as follows:

```
.col {
    background:lime; /* merely for testing*/
    display:inline-block;
}

.col20 {
    width:20%;
}

.col80 {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the css you're currently applying to these div's?

Comment: You can float the divs.

Comment: If the divs have default styling you cannot see a space in there, it should only show between inline elements. Something else is causing the spacing.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There can't be any space. Check this:

HTML:

```
<div class="col col20">
    Content left
</div>
<div class="col col80">
    Content right
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
  float: left;
}

.col20 {
  width: 20%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.col80 {
  width: 80%;
  background: #fdd;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/aktzr

Comment: Ah, the `float:left` as opposed to `display:inline-block` does the trick nicely!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using floats if you are having space issues:

**CSS**

```
.col20{
    width:20%;
    background-color:#F00;
}
.col80{
    width:80%;
    background-color:#FF0;
}
.col{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
    height:1px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/jG7gz/)